apiResource laravel problem with show update and destroy methods
I'm using apiResource using Postman I try to get a specific item ("services"), update and delete by API controller but does not work and returns null values.
Here are the details:
Services model
<?php

namespace App\Models;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Factories\HasFactory;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Services extends Model
{
    use HasFactory;
    protected $fillable= [
        'Service','Added_By'
    ];
}


ServiceController
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers\Api;

use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;
use App\Models\Services;
use App\Http\Requests\StoreServicesRequest;
use App\Http\Requests\UpdateServicesRequest;
use App\Http\Resources\ServiceResource;

class ServiceController extends Controller
{
    /**
     * Display a listing of the resource.
     */
    public function index()
    {
        dd(ServiceResource::collection((Services::query()->orderBy('id','desc')->paginate(10))));
      return  ServiceResource::collection((Services::query()->orderBy('id','desc')->paginate(10))) ;
    }
    /**
     * Store a newly created resource in storage.
     */
    public function store(StoreServicesRequest $request)
    {
        $data=$request->validated();
        $service=Services::create($data);
        return response(new ServiceResource($service),201);
    }
    /**
     * Display the specified resource.
     */
    public function show(Services $services)
    {
        dump($services);
        return new ServiceResource($services);
    }
    /**
     * Update the specified resource in storage.
     */
    public function update(UpdateServicesRequest $request, Services $services)
    {
        $data=$request->validated();
        $services->update($data);
        return new ServiceResource($services);
    }
    /**
     * Remove the specified resource from storage.
     */
    public function destroy(Services $services)
    {
       $services->delete();
       return response("", 204);

    }
}


UpdateServiceRequest
<?php

namespace App\Http\Requests;

use Illuminate\Foundation\Http\FormRequest;

class UpdateServicesRequest extends FormRequest
{
    /**
     * Determine if the user is authorized to make this request.
     */
    public function authorize(): bool
    {
        return true;
    }

    /**
     * Get the validation rules that apply to the request.
     *
     * @return array<string, \Illuminate\Contracts\Validation\ValidationRule|array<mixed>|string>
     */
    public function rules(): array
    {
        return [
            "Service"=>"required",
            "Added_By"=>"nullable",
        ];
    }
}


API route
<?php

use App\Http\Controllers\api\apiController;
use App\Http\Controllers\Api\ServiceController;
use App\Http\Controllers\Api\UserController;
use App\Http\Controllers\AuthController;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Route;

/*
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
| API Routes
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
|
| Here is where you can register API routes for your application. These
| routes are loaded by the RouteServiceProvider and all of them will
| be assigned to the "api" middleware group. Make something great!
|
*/
Route::middleware('auth:sanctum')->group(function(){
    Route::post('/logout',[AuthController::class,'logout']);    
    Route::get('/user', function (Request $request) {
            return $request->user();
        });
       

        Route::apiResource('/users', UserController::class);
        Route::apiResource("/services",ServiceController::class);


});



Route::post('login',[AuthController::class,'login']);
Route::post('register',[AuthController::class,'register']);



<?php

namespace App\Http\Resources;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use Illuminate\Http\Resources\Json\JsonResource;

class ServiceResource extends JsonResource
{
    /**
     * Transform the resource into an array.
     *
     * @return array<string, mixed>
     */
    public function toArray(Request $request): array
    {
        return [
            "id"=>$this->id,
            "Service"=>$this->Service,
            "Added_By"=>$this->Added_By,
            "Date"=>$this->created_at,
            
        ];
    }
}

When I try  to get a specific service via Postman  by http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/services/1 but gives me:
{
    "id": null,
    "Service": null,
    "Added_By": null,
    "Date": null
}

Same result when trying updating.
Also nothing is deleting when trying.
Notice that for index and store methods is working fine.

This happens because you named the variable "$services". Laravel is looking to bind to $service (/services/{service}).
More information here: (https://laravel.com/docs/11.x/controllers#restful-naming-resource-route-parameters)
Your index and store routes work fine because they don't require a parameter.

I appreciate it

public function show(Services $services)
{
    return new ServiceResource($services);
}

public function update(UpdateServicesRequest $request, Services $services)
{
    $data = $request->validated();
    $services->update($data);
    return new ServiceResource($services);
}

In your routes, ensure you are using the correct parameter for binding:
Route::apiResource("/services", ServiceController::class);


Hi ,It's the same , and it work fine when get all items or post to create a new item :  http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/services  (POST and Get work fine ) but when passing parameter get Specific item or Update a specific item or delete a specific one it dose not work ,  here the routes  that NOT work :   Get/HEAD==== api/services/{service}   PUT/PATCH====api/services/{service}       DELETE====api/services/{service}  I feel likeI have something wrong with the model binding ....   thank you for help

I wana notice you that is work fine when applying on the default model User:: but when creating new model like in my case the PUT POST(for update) DELETE do note work  , may I add something in config/Auth.php ?
